# What is a vbmeta partition?

Tags: partitions, magisk

One of the optional steps of the Magisk installation steps says,

> (Optional) If your device has a separate vbmeta partition, you can patch the vbmeta partition with command:
>
> ```
> fastboot flash vbmeta --disable-verity --disable-verification vbmeta.img
> ```

What is the `vbmeta` partition it's referring to there? I didn't do that step. What may occur from that?

Comment: It is for verified boot. A lot of details are described here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/avb/+/master/README.md#The-VBMeta-struct It also contains information about what is stored in vbmeta partition.

Comment: Bootloop :( // not necessarily, but on some devices, like Samsung and more that's why it is recommended as "optional", if you have that partition

Comment: @Robert Thanks a lot for the link. Bless you! It would be nice a summarized but complete answer for newbies. :) I am learning myself about ROMs and, believe me, the information is so fragmented and written in expert jargon that I am just craving for clarity and didactic contributions. :_(